# Store Date to a .txt file only once using c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have written code that stores the date to a .txt file as shown. I am able to store the current date and time. I want that the date should be set only once when the application is executed for the first time.

**Installed Date**: Set to the date when the application is executed the first time and should not change irrespective of how many time the application is executed

I am trying to implement 30Days licensing. I want that when the application is executed for the very first time, the date when he executed the application should be stored into the .txt file and should not change, so that the remaining days could be calculated on the basis of that. My main aim is to stop the user from using my application after 30 days

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string fileName = @"C:\\Temp\\test.txt";

        try
        {

            // Create a new file 
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName));

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(fileName))
            {

                sw.WriteLine("Thermo Licensing System file");
                sw.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
                sw.WriteLine("Installed Date: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());


                DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
                DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
                sw.WriteLine("License Expires After"+" "+newDate);

                int numberOfDays = newDate.Subtract(date).Days;
                sw.WriteLine("Number of Days Remaining: " + "  " + numberOfDays.ToString());
                sw.Close();


            }

            // Write file contents on console. 
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
            {
                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
                     Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}

Output (.txt file)

Thermo Licensing System file
------------------------------------
Installed Date: 20-05-2014 16:01:42
License Expires After 20-06-2014 16:01:42
Number Of Days Remaining
```

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Thanks for replying.Would you please give me a code snippet

Comment: There isn't a way to check that an app is running for the first time unless you store it outside the app and read it on startup. Why don't you take a step back and explain what you are trying to do

Comment: @GrantWinney I am trying to implement 30Days licensing.I want that when the application is executed for the very first time,hte date when he executed the application should be stored into the .txt file and should not change,so that the remaining days could be calculated on the basis of that.My main ami is to stop the user from using my application after 30 days

Comment: @psubsee2003 I am already storing the date and time when the application was executed to a .txt file.I want that this date should be stored only once and should not change irrespective of how many times the application is executed

Comment: @user2614235. Can you tell `Why you delete existing file?` And `what will be source of installed date when application is executed 2nd time?`

Comment: @HassanNisar I have made changes to the code.I wont be deleting the file.When the applivcation is executed for the first time the date would be stored to a .txt file and when the application is executed 2nd time,this date information will be read from the .txt file

Answer (score 1):

You're already checking to see if the file exists, so there's no need for a variable.

```
if (File.Exists(fileName)) {
    // Test to make sure the contents of the file are something you
    // created, and not another file with the same name.
}
else {
    // Continue on with your logic to create the file and add the dates.
}
```

Comment: I didn't get you @Krillgar.i hope you understood my question.thanks

Comment: You want to only create the file once, correct? Well if the file already exists, then you shouldn't create it a second time. Right now, you're deleting the file, and creating it again if it exists. If the file exists, don't delete it.

Comment: I want the date should be stored and set only once here in the .txt file

Installed Date: Set to the date when the application is executed the first time and should not change irrespective of how many time the application is executed

Comment: Right. So if the file exists (and has the contents you're expecting, not another file with the same name in the location), then **LEAVE THE FILE ALONE**.

Comment: I have made changes to the code.Now what next?

Comment: You should have stuck with the original code. Firstly, & important to the site, your changes invalidate every existing comment and my answer, confusing any people who come across this question later. Secondly, you still have two completely separate actions you need to perform. You're still not checking to see what the expiration date is, so after their 30 day period, they'll still be able to use your program. You need to take a step back & go back over what you're trying to do in pseudo-code instead of just tossing code together hoping it does what you want. You don't understand your problem.